# r combine two dataframes not the same and with timestamps

Tags: r, dataframe, sqldf

I am new to R and trying to change some code from SAS to R, but I'm stuck on one part.  I currently can't think of a sample data set I can post that would represent my issue.

Dataframe name1 has 5 columns and 483 rows.

Dataframe name2 has 27 columns and over 30000 rows.

I currently have this in SAS:

```
 proc sql;
 create table name_c as
 select a.*, b.*
 from work.name1 a inner join work.name2 b
 on a.name = b.name
 where b.start_time <= a.p_start_time:
 quit;
```

I tried to use sqldf

```
   name_c <- sqldf("select a.*, b.* from name1 a inner join name2 b on
                    a.name = b.name
                    where b.start_time <= a.p_start_time")
```

but get error message:
**Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  table name2 has no column named 
In addition: Warning message:
In field_types[] <- field_types[names(data)] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length**

The results I'm hoping for would be all columns but filtered by the timestamp as mentioned in the sqldf code.

Comment: Can you provide sample data that triggers this error?

Comment: is there a reason why you just aren't using merge?  you can than subset to whatever condition you want.

Comment: `subset(merge(name1, name2, by="name"), start_time <= p_start_time)`

Comment: @Parfait that worked, as well as Peter_Evan post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am rusty with SAS, but (from what I understand) you should be able to use dplyr to do an inner_join and then filter. Below is a toy example:

```
 library(dplyr)

 Name <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
 Year <- c(2006,2007,2008,2009,2006,2007,2008,2009,2006,2007,2008,2009)
 Qtr.1 <- as.numeric(c(15,12,22,10,12,16,13,23,11,13,17,14))
 Qtr.2 <- as.numeric(c(14,32,62,40,72,26,43,53,14,53,67,17))
 Qtr.3 <- as.numeric(c(55,52,52,50,52,56,53,53,51,15,15,54))
 Qtr.4 <- as.numeric(c(65,72,52,40,52,66,63,24,51,63,57,84))
 DF <- data.frame(Name,Year,Qtr.1,Qtr.2,Qtr.3,Qtr.4)


 Name2 <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,5,2,9,3,7,3)
 Year2 <- c(2016,2034,2008,2009,2034,2007,2008,2009,2006,2007,2008,2009)
 Qtr.1.2 <- as.numeric(c(15,12,22,10,12,16,13,23,11,13,17,14))
 Qtr.2.2 <- as.numeric(c(14,32,62,40,72,26,43,53,14,53,67,17))
 Qtr.3.2 <- as.numeric(c(55,52,52,50,52,56,53,53,51,15,15,54))
 Qtr.4.2 <- as.numeric(c(65,72,52,40,52,66,63,34,51,63,57,84))
 DF2 <- data.frame(Name2,Year2,Qtr.1.2,Qtr.2.2,Qtr.3.2,Qtr.4.2)


 #using dplyr's inner_join + filter fuctions
 x <- inner_join(DF, DF2 , by = c("Name" = "Name2"))
 x <- x %>% filter(Year <= Year2)
 x
    # A tibble: 31 x 11
   Name  Year Qtr.1 Qtr.2 Qtr.3 Qtr.4 Year2
1     1  2006    15    14    55    65  2016
.....
```